# How to replace selected text in vimscript

Tags: vim

I have some specific parts of files with unformated xml code. I need to write a vimscript function that selects the text and calls xmllint over it.

I know I can do this on the command line `:'<,'>!xmllint --format -`

But I really need to do the same in a vimscript function and I don't know how to make something like `normal!` call for visual.

I tried this but it does not work correctly :

```
function! MyFormat()
    ... stuff done here
    let startl = line("'<")
    let endl = line("'>")
    let line = getline(startl, endl)
    let r = system('echo "' . join(line, "") . '" | xmllint --format -')

    call setline('.', r)
endfunction
```

Comment: You *need* to or you *want* to? The command you gave seems to do the job fine so what problem, exactly, are you trying to solve and how do you plan to use that function?

Comment: And your question lacks the level of detail necessary for it to be answered properly, most importantly, *what you have tried*.

Comment: I have updated my question. I think maybe I could have an issue with quotes in string injecte in the system function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every line in a Vim script is an Ex command. Since you already have a working Ex command, you might as well use it.

```
function! MyFormat()
    " ... stuff done here
    '<,'>!xmllint --format -
    " ... more stuff done here
endfunction
```

But, again, data is missing so this might work… or not, be sufficient… or not, etc.